# Dockerfile pytest segmentation fault

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pytest

I've been having issues running pytest on docker. The pytest command runs perfectly well locally, but docker won't behave.

The Dockerfile is

```
# Use the official Python base image
FROM python:3.11-bullseye

RUN pip install numpy && pip install setuptools

# Copy the debPackages.txt file
COPY debPackages.txt .

# Install Qt6 dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install $(grep -vE "^\s*#" debPackages.txt  | tr "\n" " ") -y

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements.txt file
COPY requirements.txt .

# Upgrade pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Install the Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the project files
COPY . .

# Copy the test files
COPY ./tests ./tests

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=true

# Expose the port the application runs on
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["coverage", "run", "-m", "pytest"]
```

I'm running the build with `sudo docker build -f docker/Dockerfile --tag merlot .` and the test with `sudo docker run merlot:latest`. The test seg faults with the following output:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.11.5, pytest-7.4.2, pluggy-1.3.0 -- /usr/local/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /app
configfile: pytest.ini
testpaths: tests
plugins: cov-4.1.0, mock-3.11.1
collecting ... collected 9 items

tests/testMerlot.py::TestMerlotBrowser::testBrowser Fatal Python error: Aborted

Current thread 0x00007faafec9a740 (most recent call first):
  File "/app/tests/testMerlot.py", line 11 in setup_method
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 902 in call_fixture_func
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 1123 in pytest_fixture_setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 77 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 115 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 493 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 1069 in execute
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 693 in _compute_fixture_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 607 in _get_active_fixturedef
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 585 in getfixturevalue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 566 in _fillfixtures
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 1795 in setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 494 in setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 157 in pytest_runtest_setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 77 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 115 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 493 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 262 in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 341 in from_call
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 261 in call_runtest_hook
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 222 in call_and_report
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 127 in runtestprotocol
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 114 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 77 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 115 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 493 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 350 in pytest_runtestloop
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 77 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 115 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 493 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 325 in _main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 271 in wrap_session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 318 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 77 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 115 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 493 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 169 in main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 192 in console_main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest/__main__.py", line 5 in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coverage/execfile.py", line 211 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 861 in do_run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 684 in command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 973 in main
  File "/usr/local/bin/coverage", line 8 in <module>

Extension modules: numpy.core._multiarray_umath, numpy.core._multiarray_tests, numpy.linalg._umath_linalg, numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal, numpy.random._common, numpy.random.bit_generator, numpy.random._bounded_integers, numpy.random._mt19937, numpy.random.mtrand, numpy.random._philox, numpy.random._pcg64, numpy.random._sfc64, numpy.random._generator, xxsubtype, shiboken6.Shiboken, PySide6.QtCore, PySide6.QtGui, PySide6.QtWidgets (total: 18)
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007faafec9a740 (most recent call first):
  File "/app/tests/testMerlot.py", line 11 in setup_method
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 902 in call_fixture_func
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 1123 in pytest_fixture_setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 77 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 115 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 493 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 1069 in execute
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 693 in _compute_fixture_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 607 in _get_active_fixturedef
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 585 in getfixturevalue
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/fixtures.py", line 566 in _fillfixtures
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 1795 in setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 494 in setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 157 in pytest_runtest_setup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 77 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 115 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 493 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 262 in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 341 in from_call
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 261 in call_runtest_hook
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 222 in call_and_report
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 127 in runtestprotocol
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 114 in pytest_runtest_protocol
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 77 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 115 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 493 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 350 in pytest_runtestloop
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 77 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 115 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 493 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 325 in _main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 271 in wrap_session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 318 in pytest_cmdline_main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 77 in _multicall
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 115 in _hookexec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 493 in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 169 in main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 192 in console_main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pytest/__main__.py", line 5 in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coverage/execfile.py", line 211 in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 861 in do_run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 684 in command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coverage/cmdline.py", line 973 in main
  File "/usr/local/bin/coverage", line 8 in <module>

Extension modules: numpy.core._multiarray_umath, numpy.core._multiarray_tests, numpy.linalg._umath_linalg, numpy.fft._pocketfft_internal, numpy.random._common, numpy.random.bit_generator, numpy.random._bounded_integers, numpy.random._mt19937, numpy.random.mtrand, numpy.random._philox, numpy.random._pcg64, numpy.random._sfc64, numpy.random._generator, xxsubtype, shiboken6.Shiboken, PySide6.QtCore, PySide6.QtGui, PySide6.QtWidgets (total: 18)
make: *** [Makefile:27: test] Error 139
```

***the whole project can be found here: https://gitlab.com/glicka/merlot

Comment: Note you might want to add yourself to the `docker` group, as that would probably allow you to avoid having to use `sudo` to run docker.

Answer (score 0):

I added `ENV QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` to my Dockerfile and was able to discover a lot of plugins that aren't included in `python:3.11-bullseye`. After updating my `debPackages.txt` file to include all these plugins my docker tests run (they fail, but they run).